# Bench start doesn’t work properly (install erpnext on windows 10 using docker)

Tags: docker-compose, erpnext

I am trying to run erpnext on windows 10 using docker. I have followed installation links from the following link https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker/tree/develop1
when I reached the following command
bench start
I had the following output and I coudn’t access localhost:8000

> frappe@d8d62e95e69b:~/frappe-bench$ bench start 2017-10-10 16:33:18
>   [196] [WARNING] Your terminal is not configured to receive UTF-8
>   encoded text. Please adjust your locale settings or force UTF-8 output
>   by setting PYTHONIOENCODING=“utf-8”. 16:33:21 system |
>   redis_socketio.1 started (pid=213) 16:33:21 redis_socketio.1 |
>   /bin/sh: 1: redis-server: not found 16:33:21 system | redis_socketio.1
>   stopped (rc=127) 16:33:21 system | worker_default.1 started (pid=230)
>   16:33:21 system | watch.1 started (pid=218) 16:33:21 system |
>   worker_long.1 started (pid=216) 16:33:21 system | redis_cache.1
>   started (pid=226) 16:33:21 system | redis_queue.1 started (pid=219)
>   16:33:21 redis_queue.1 | /bin/sh: 1: redis-server: not found 16:33:21
>   system | redis_queue.1 stopped (rc=127) 16:33:21 redis_cache.1 |
>   /bin/sh: 1: redis-server: not found 16:33:21 system | redis_cache.1
>   stopped (rc=127) 16:33:21 system | schedule.1 started (pid=225)
>   16:33:21 system | socketio.1 started (pid=228) 16:33:22 system | web.1
>   started (pid=223) 16:33:22 system | worker_short.1 started (pid=229)
>   16:33:22 system | sending SIGTERM to worker_long.1 (pid 216) 16:33:22
>   system | sending SIGTERM to watch.1 (pid 218) 16:33:22 system |
>   sending SIGTERM to web.1 (pid 223) 16:33:22 system | sending SIGTERM
>   to schedule.1 (pid 225) 16:33:22 system | sending SIGTERM to
>   worker_default.1 (pid 230) 16:33:22 system | sending SIGTERM to
>   socketio.1 (pid 228) 16:33:22 system | sending SIGTERM to
>   worker_short.1 (pid 229) 16:33:22 system | schedule.1 stopped (rc=-15)
>   16:33:22 system | worker_long.1 stopped (rc=-15) 16:33:22 system |
>   worker_default.1 stopped (rc=-15) 16:33:22 system | watch.1 stopped
>   (rc=-15) 16:33:22 system | worker_short.1 stopped (rc=-15) 16:33:22
>   system | socketio.1 stopped (rc=-15) 16:33:22 system | web.1 stopped
>   (rc=-15) frappe@d8d62e95e69b:~/frappe-bench$

It is my first time installing erpnext and I don’t know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the discuss.erpnext.com forum for detailed answers to this particular issue. You will find many answers related to this.

As you do, try the following:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

That should do the trick.
The specific forum post listing this issue: https://discuss.erpnext.com/t/server-error-brokenfilesystem/17864/9